# How to pass arguments to scala file in the sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt

```
cat test.scala

println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")
```

I've found that for loading file there is :load command but how can I pass arguments to script?
I'm using sbt console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, this is not something you can do in the `sbt console`. You can run your file as a script with:

```
scala test.scala
```

If you want to load it in the `sbt console` I think you have to make a function of your code and wrap it in an object, because otherwise it will not compile:

```
object TestProgram {
    def greet(name: String) = println("Hello, " + name)
}
```

which you can then call from `sbt console` with `TestProgram.greet("world")`

Comment: I think you have a typo in the first sentence: "can't do"

Comment: No, actually I meant that you cannot  just run a script from the sbt console, but that you can make a function out of it and then call it from the sbt console. But that is not the same thing, although you could achieve the same thing with it.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it: "**not** something you **can do**" — I missed "not".